# Can I convert "sparse" contour to "dense" contour in Python?

Tags: python, opencv

OpenCV's `findContours()` function provides contour compression.

1. If `cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE` option is passed, contour is not approximated and every point on the contour is returned (i.e., "dense" contour).
2. If `cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE` option is passed, the points forming a straight line segment are compressed so that the points in between are gone (i.e., "sparse" contour).

I want to transform a sparse contour to a dense contour. I considered interpolating the sparse points, but I want the "exact" result without any parameter. In other words, I want what I would get if I re-drew the contour from sparse points and re-applied `findContours()` with `cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE` option. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: that'll involve some kind of Bresenham algorithm. OpenCV has a LineIterator class, but only in C++. you could implement Bresenham yourself. you could also file a feature request on the opencv github.

Comment: Draw your sparse contour as white on black background. Then compute a new dense contour for it from that binary image.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE` performs lossless compression of the points, i.e., it reduces the number of points but does not "approximate" the original curve.

This means that the angle between the line segments from `cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE` is always n*pi/4. Thus densifying the contour can be done by simple interpolation:

1. If line has angle n*pi/2, interpolate with distnace 1. If the angle is (2n + 1)*pi/4, interpolate with distance sqrt(2).
2. Round the coordinates of interpolated points.